# Need Excel Goal Seek Logic

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I need the know how excel goal seeks works.

i have a method (not simple x2+y polynomial function), this method is written in c# and is lot complex. (which access database)

say this function has 10 parameters and gives one result. i need to know how excel goal seek works if i give the result and want to seek one of the parameter.

i saw similar post which explains bisection, i dont see anywhere i can specifiy the result and seek a parameter.

i.e

if i have

result = function(p1,p2,...p10)

given :

result, p1,p2...p9

need to seek :
p10

As i said this function cannot be laid in simple polynomial equation.

i need exactly how microsoft excel 2010 does goal seek in this case.

Comment: i guess it is simply newton-raphson method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method