# Get excel to continually 'goal seek'

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with numerous inputs, but one output (a price).

I want to get excel to automatically update one of the inputs (call it input 1) in order to keep the price constant whilst I adjust the other inputs.

I know 'goal seek' can do this, but I don't want to have to rerun the goal seek everytime I adjust another input. I particularly do not want to have to do this because I want to use scenario analysis to adjust the other inputs individually, and see how input 1 would need to change in order to keep the output (price) constant.

Someone asked a similar question here: [Need Excel Goal Seek Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698293/need-excel-goal-seek-logic)

However there is no useful answer given to that post.

Would be most appreciative if anyone could help out please.

Thanks,

Timothy

Comment: ... If you always want excel to update `input 1`, why not convert it to a formula since that is now your variable - You may need to wirte a VBA function to calculate it's value, but that should accomplish your desired scenario...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a VBA function calling the Range.GoalSeek method, in the Worksheet_Change event.  When you change another cell, the goal seek code should run automatically.

Here is documentation on that method: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb209907(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb209907%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I've had a go at this, but from how I understand it, I need to keep running the script for it to update each time rather than doing it automatically.

Comment: Catch the worksheet_change event and check the changed cell to see if it is your input cell.  If it is, then call the aforementioned Range.GoalSeek method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a circular reference to automatically solve an equation if the equation can be set up to converge under fixed point iteration.